Can't recovery postgrsqldb ( template1" user:"postgres" failed to start in 90 second )
Can someone help me to fix this issue:
ERROR:  recovery is checking if postmaster is started
DETAIL:  postmaster on hostname:"postgresqldb02" database:"template1" user:"postgres" failed to start in 90 second.

 node_id |    hostname    | port | status | pg_status | lb_weight |  role   | pg_role | select_cnt | load_balance_node | replication_delay | replication_state | replication_sync_state | last_status_change
---------+----------------+------+--------+-----------+-----------+---------+---------+------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+------------------------+---------------------
 0       | postgresqldb01 | 5432 | up     | up        | 0.500000  | primary | primary | 52         | true              | 0                 |                   |                        | 2024-06-03 09:05:36
 1       | postgresqldb02 | 5432 | down   | down      | 0.500000  | standby | unknown | 0          | false             | 0                 | streaming         | async                  | 2024-06-03 09:03:58
(2 rows)

==> Postgresqldb 02 log;
-rw-r-----  1 postgres adm      10019 Jun  4 01:49 postgresql-12-main.log
root@postgresqldb02:/var/log/postgresql# cat postgresql-12-main.log
2024-06-03 09:33:19.390 UTC [52442] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 12.19 (Ubuntu 12.19-1.pgdg20.04+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.2) 9.4.0, 64-bit
2024-06-03 09:33:19.390 UTC [52442] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432
2024-06-03 09:33:19.393 UTC [52442] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2024-06-03 09:33:19.423 UTC [52443] LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2024-06-03 09:33:18 UTC
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
postgres@postgresqldb01: Permission denied (publickey,password).
2024-06-03 09:33:19.532 UTC [52443] LOG:  entering standby mode
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
postgres@postgresqldb01: Permission denied (publickey,password).
2024-06-03 09:33:19.608 UTC [52443] LOG:  redo starts at 0/2C000028
2024-06-03 09:33:19.611 UTC [52443] LOG:  consistent recovery state reached at 0/2C000100
2024-06-03 09:33:19.611 UTC [52442] LOG:  database system is ready to accept read only connections
Permission denied, please try again.

Can someone help me to resolve this problem, so that I can recover?
